# How to get the value of a first key-value pair in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to sole exercise where I have dictionary like this:

```
[{"state" : 'Maine', 'capital': 'Augusta'}, {'country': 'Spain', "capital" : "Madrid"}]
```

Output is supposed to be:

```
["The capital of Maine is Augusta", "The capital of Spain is Madrid"]
```

My problem stems from the fact that the first key can be either state or country so I cannot just use that key name to access value, so how can I print the first key value if the name can be different across inputs?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code so far.

Comment: Theres no code so far because I have no slightest clue how to get to it

Comment: Well then, I posted an answer :)

Comment: Where? I cannot see your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [{"state" : 'Maine', 'capital': 'Augusta'}, {'country': 'Spain', "capital" : "Madrid"}]
result = [ "The capital of {} is {}".format( d['state'] if 'state' in d else d['country'], d['capital']) for d in l ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is so easy I can understand it! I cannot wait until I will be able to come up with something like this on my own, dzięki!

Answer (score 0):

```
In [3]: out = []

In [4]: for i in d:
   ...:     if 'state' in i:
   ...:         out.append('The capital of {} of is {}'.format(i['state'], i['capital']))
   ...:     else:
   ...:         out.append('The capital of {} of is {}'.format(i['country'], i['capital']))
   ...:

In [5]: out
Out[5]: ['The capital of Maine of is Augusta', 'The capital of Spain of is Madrid']
```

Comment: What is that "In [3]: out = []"? I have never seen this syntax

Comment: It's initializing an empty list

Comment: This answer is in the format of an interactive python session.  The lines starting with `In [#]:`  show the input from the programmer.  Lines starting with `Out [#]:`  show the programs output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dict.get` method. It will return a default value if the key is not present.

```
a = [{"state" : 'Maine', 'capital': 'Augusta'}, {'country': 'Spain', "capital" : "Madrid"}]
for d in a:
    place = d.get('state',d.get('country',None))
    s = 'The capital of {} is {}'.format(place,d['capital'])
    print(s)
    # or
    print("The capital of {}{} is {}".format(d.get('state',''),d.get('country',''),d['capital']))
```

Comment: Interesting. Does the list of dictionaries in my example accurately represent your list of dictionaries (I copied directly from your question)? Are **any** of your dictionaries missing both keys? My example solution works for the given list. As does Błotosmętek's answer below which you commented does not work.

Comment: I deleted that comment because his solution actually works, I just forgot to end my function with return instead of print. 

List of dictionaries are being generated by exercise, I only know this one above but much more dictionaries are being tested